# Embed video in PDF with beamer under Ubuntu

Tags: beamer, pdf, ubuntu, embedding, movie15

I'm stuck in embedding a video into a PDF presentation with beamer. The problem is not the actual tex code, but the fact that I'm using Linux Ubuntu 10.04.

The video is not reproduced, with evince it looks like it is not even present, with Acrobat Reader it says I need a media player that for my OS doesn't exist. With Okular also it doesn't work.

I searched in the web, I saw that this problem is quite popular, but no solution works for me.

The only way I manage to play the video is using the multimedia package and making a hyperref to the video, but it's not embedded, it plays outside the PDF.

Comment: Hm.. this is a common, but not LaTeX-related problem. AFAIK it's an unfortunate matter of fact that there is no PDF viewer available for Linux that can play video in place. (I think this question should be migrated to some PDF or Linux-related SE site)

Comment: As @Daniel states this might be better suited for a different SE site like http://askubuntu.com/. I can migrate it there.

Comment: I talked to the AskUbuntu mods and they would accept it. Could you check that this issue is really Ubuntu related, i.e. test the created PDF under Windows as well. The question should be a little rephrased then, like "How to make embedded videos work in PDFs" etc.

Comment: I am interested in this question too, so it would be nice to see it migrated to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes impressive works: http://impressive.sourceforge.net/. Install it through apt-get as you need some dependencies to get it working. Be sure to have mplayer installed.